# Multiple lists into one data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

So I'm running a package in which the output of the function I'm using is something similar to this:

```
        area     ID   structure
1       150       1     house
```

I have several of these which I get by looping through some stuff. Basically this is my loop function:

```
for (k in 1:length(models)) {
    for (l in 1:length(patients)) {
        print(result[[l]][[k]])
        tableData[[l]][[k]] <- do.call(rbind, result[[l]][[k]])
    }
}
```

So the `print(result[[l]][[k]])` gives the output I showed you in the beginning. So my issue is to put all of these into one dataframe. And so far it just doesn't work, i.e. the `do.call` function, which I have read is the one to use when combining lists into dataframes.

So where am I going wrong here ?

Updated:

`dput()` output (area = value in this case):

```
list(list(structure(list(value = 0.0394797760472196, ID = "1 house", 
    structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "wood", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
"ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(value = 0.0394797760472196, ID = "1 house", 
        structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "stone", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
    "ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")), 
    list(structure(list(value = 0.0306923865158472, ID = "2 house", 
        structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "wood", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
    "ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(value = 0.0306923865158472, ID = "2 house", 
            structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "stone", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
        "ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
        ), class = "data.frame")))
list(list(structure(list(value = 0.0394797760472196, ID = "1 house", 
    structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "wood", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
"ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(value = 0.0394797760472196, ID = "1 house", 
        structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "stone", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
    "ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame")), 
    list(structure(list(value = 0.0306923865158472, ID = "2 house", 
        structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "wood", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
    "ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = "data.frame"), 
        structure(list(value = 0.0306923865158472, ID = "2 house", 
            structure = "house", model = structure(1L, .Label = "stone", class = "factor")), .Names = c("value", 
        "ID", "structure", "model"), row.names = c(NA, -1L
        ), class = "data.frame")))
```

Comment: Please `dput()` your object *result* and post that gobbledygook here which we know how to work with. This allows us to recreate your object. If *result* is very big, use `head()`: `dput(head(result))`.

Comment: I agree since it is very difficult to understand what your objects are ... str(result) and str(tableData) please

Comment: Sorry. I have now updated OP with dput() output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: I initially used `purrr::map_dfr` to solve this problem, but `purrr::reduce` is much more appropriate.

The list nesting means we have to bind rows together twice. Here's a solution using the `purrr` and `dplyr` packages and assigning your `dput` list to the variable `my_list`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

my_df <- reduce(my_list, bind_rows)
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector

#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): Unequal factor levels: coercing to character
#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector

#> Warning in bind_rows_(x, .id): binding character and factor vector,
#> coercing into character vector
my_df
#>        value      ID structure model
#> 1 0.03947978 1 house     house  wood
#> 2 0.03947978 1 house     house stone
#> 3 0.03069239 2 house     house  wood
#> 4 0.03069239 2 house     house stone
```

I find map-ing with purrr way more intuitive than `do.call`. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This is excellent. So much cleaner than what I would have come up myself. Should I just ignore the errors, or can I do anything about them ? :)

Comment: The warnings are from your dataframes having strings as factors. If you convert these factors to characters beforehand, you'll avoid these warnings

Comment: That's even better... Thank you so much.